# Parse CSV Data with Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

I am trying to return a specific cell value based on two criteria.

The logic:

`If ClientID = 1 and BranchID = 1, puts SurveyID`

Using Ruby 1.9.3, I want to basically look through an excel file and for two specific values located within the `ClientID` and `BranchID` column, return the corresponding value in the `SurveyID` column.

This is what I have so far, which I found during my online searches. It seemed promising, but no luck:

```
require 'csv'

# Load file
csv_fname = 'FS_Email_Test.csv'

# Key is the column to check, value is what to match
search_criteria = { 'ClientID' => '1', 
                   'BranchID' => '1' }

options = { :headers      =>  :first_row,
            :converters   =>  [ :numeric ] }

# Save `matches` and a copy of the `headers`
matches = nil
headers = nil

# Iterate through the `csv` file and locate where
# data matches the options.

CSV.open( csv_fname, "r", options ) do |csv|
  matches = csv.find_all do |row|
    match = true
    search_criteria.keys.each do |key|
      match = match && ( row[key] == search_criteria[key] )
    end
    match
  end
  headers = csv.headers
end

# Once matches are found, we print the results
# for a specific row. The row `row[8]` is
# tied specifically to a notes field.

matches.each do |row|
  row = row[1]
  puts row
end
```

I know the last bit of code following `matches.each do |row|` is invalid, but I left it in in hopes that it will make sense to someone else.

How can I write `puts surveyID if ClientID == 1 & BranchID == 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close indeed. Your only error was setting the values of the `search_criteria` hash to strings `'1'` instead of numbers. Since you have `converters: :numeric` in there the `find_all` was comparing `1` to `'1'` and getting `false`. You could just change that and you're done.

Alternatively this should work for you.

The key is the line

```
Hash[row].select { |k,v| search_criteria[k] } == search_criteria
```

`Hash[row]` converts the row into a hash instead of an array of arrays. Select generates a new hash that has only those elements that appear in `search_criteria`. Then just compare the two hashes to see if they're the same.

```
require 'csv'

# Load file
csv_fname = 'FS_Email_Test.csv'

# Key is the column to check, value is what to match
search_criteria = {
  'ClientID' => 1,
  'BranchID' => 1,
}

options = {
  headers:    :first_row,
  converters: :numeric,
}

# Save `matches` and a copy of the `headers`
matches = nil
headers = nil

# Iterate through the `csv` file and locate where
# data matches the options.

CSV.open(csv_fname, 'r', options) do |csv|
  matches = csv.find_all do |row|
    Hash[row].select { |k,v| search_criteria[k] } == search_criteria
  end
  headers = csv.headers
end

p headers


# Once matches are found, we print the results
# for a specific row. The row `row[8]` is
# tied specifically to a notes field.

matches.each { |row| puts row['surveyID'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly...

```
require 'csv'

b_headers = false
client_id_col = 0
branch_id_col = 0
survey_id_col = 0

CSV.open('FS_Email_Test.csv') do |file|
  file.find_all do |row|
    if b_headers == false then

      client_id_col = row.index("ClientID")
      branch_id_col = row.index("BranchID")
      survey_id_col = row.index("SurveyID")
      b_headers = true

      if branch_id_col.nil? || client_id_col.nil? || survey_id_col.nil? then
        puts "Invalid csv file - Missing one of these columns (or no headers):\nClientID\nBranchID\nSurveyID"
        break
      end

    else
      puts row[survey_id_col] if row[branch_id_col] == "1" && row[client_id_col] == "1"
    end

  end
end
```